# Use of Case in Update query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use Case in Update query and it gives me an error that there is an Incorrect syntax near case. I am not sure where?! This is in SQL 2005

I am sending the date to the stored procedure. If the Date sent is '01/01/1905', it has to save null else the real date entered. I am really not sure what is wrong in this statement.

```
Update Manifest set Notes = @Notes, IsCustom = @IsCustom,
CASE WHEN @ProofSent = CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/1905') THEN NULL ELSE @ProofSent END,
CASE WHEN @ProofApproved = CONVERT(datetime, '02/01/1905') THEN NULL ELSE @ProofApproved END
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Case needs a left side column, what do you intend this case statement do?

Comment: I got it. Your answer works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be sth like this:

```
Update Manifest set Notes = @Notes, IsCustom = @IsCustom,
Column1 = 
    CASE WHEN @ProofSent = CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/1905') THEN NULL 
    ELSE @ProofSent END,
Column2=
    CASE WHEN @ProofApproved = CONVERT(datetime, '02/01/1905') THEN NULL 
    ELSE @ProofApproved END
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared what column it should be set to:

```
Update Manifest set Notes = @Notes, IsCustom = @IsCustom,
    ProofSent = CASE WHEN @ProofSent = CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/1905') THEN NULL ELSE @ProofSent END,
    ProofApproved = CASE WHEN @ProofApproved = CONVERT(datetime, '02/01/1905') THEN NULL ELSE @ProofApproved END
```